# Why does this iframe display correctly in Chrome but not Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In Sharepoint 2010, I am able to create a web part that displays the iframe map below when I use Chrome, but not IE 11. I tried using the Content Editor web part and the Page Viewer web part, but neither worked. It just displayed a blank square with a  "Clickable Map" link at the bottom. I think it's an issue with Sharepoint because the page below opens for me in IE, but not in the Sharepoint web part using IE. But then again, it might be a browser issue because Chrome displays the web part perfectly via Sharepoint. Is there a way to get the map to display in internet explorer?

https://createaclickablemap.com/map.php?&id=64357&maplocation=false&online=true

Answer (score 0):

In sharepoint masterpages there is something like this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` which tells the internet explorer to render the page like you are viewing the page with an internet explorer 8. So even if you are using an IE11, the browser still uses the old engine.

Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256968/overwrite-x-ua-compatible-meta-in-sharepoint-2010) will help since it sounds like a related question.